# Reading an uint32_t from a byte stream

Tags: c++

I'm reading bytes from a PNG image via `std::basic_ifstream<std::uint8_t>`. I'm having problems reading a sequence of 4 bytes that should be interpreted as 32 bit int.

```
std::uint32_t read_chunk_length(std::basic_ifstream<std::uint8_t> &ifs) {
    std::uint32_t length;
    ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<std::uint8_t*>(&length), 4);
    return length;
}
```

When reading a sequence that is 00 00 00 0d and should thus be 0xd (or 13), the above function gives me 0xd000000 (or 218103808 instead). Apologies if the question is trivial.

Comment: Have you checked how it's stored? Byte order-wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [byte ordering issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) - the stream on disk contains the bytes in the opposite order ([big endian as specified in the PNG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#7Integers-and-byte-order)) than your architecture mandates for integers (likely little-endian). You have to manually reverse the order of bytes to solve this.